# Width of drawn list box?

Tags: vb.net, properties, user-controls, combobox, listbox

I've created a custom combobox that uses a custom instance of a listbox control as the dropdown menu.

In order to customize the selection highlight of the listbox, I had to change its 'DrawMode' property to 'OwnerDrawFixed' and added the following code:

```
Private Sub _listBox_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs)
    If e.Index >= 0 Then
        e.DrawBackground()
        If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
            Using br = New LinearGradientBrush(e.Bounds, ColorSelectionListbox, ColorSelectionListbox, 0)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds)
            End Using
        End If
        Using b As New SolidBrush(ColorTextListbox)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(_listBox.GetItemText(_listBox.Items(e.Index)), e.Font, b, e.Bounds)
        End Using
        e.DrawFocusRectangle()

        RaiseEvent DrawItem(Me, e)
    End If
End Sub
```

But with this, the width that I set for it is ignored and becomes a fixed width of 15 or so pixels.

How can I set the width of the owner-drawn control? Currently I have it as a property:

```
Public Property DropDownWidth() As Integer
    Get
        Return _dropDownWidth
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _dropDownWidth = value
        _listBox.Width = value
        Invalidate(True)
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: I am not sure why you are saying that the width is fixed (you can set 'OwnerDrawFixed' and affect the width of the ListBox as much as you wish). In any case, both pieces of code are unrelated. Can you please post all your (relevant) code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the rest of the code that is relevant, but nevermind.. I fixed the issue by setting the `Autosize` property of `_controlHost` to `False`. I had it set to `True` in order to display all items within the list (without having to define a dropdown maximum) but for some reason it behaves differently when the `DrawMode` is set to `OwnerDraw`.

```
    _listBox = New ListBox()
    _listBox.IntegralHeight = True
    _listBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    _listBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One
    _listBox.BindingContext = New BindingContext()
    _dropDownWidth = Me.Width
    _listBox.Width = _dropDownWidth

    _controlHost = New ToolStripControlHost(_listBox)
    _controlHost.Padding = New Padding(0)
    _controlHost.Margin = New Padding(0)
    _controlHost.AutoSize = False 'Used to be variable property _dropDownAutoSize

    _popupControl = New ToolStripDropDown()
    _popupControl.Padding = New Padding(0)
    _popupControl.Margin = New Padding(0)
    _popupControl.AutoSize = True '
    _popupControl.DropShadowEnabled = False
    _popupControl.Items.Add(_controlHost)
```